# Quickly multiply all combinations of matrices in a list

Tags: r, list, matrix-multiplication, reduce

I have a symmetric matrix `Siginv` and a list `Z` containing `N` matrices of size `TxK`.

I have three approaches to compute what I need (see below). The first one literally takes the formula, and is slow, as expected. Are there faster ways of doing what I do?

```
library(microbenchmark)

K <- 2
N <- 50
Siginv <- matrix(rnorm(N^2), ncol=N)
Siginv[lower.tri(Siginv)] <- t(Siginv)[lower.tri(Siginv)] # just some symmetric matrix

Tdim <- 400
Z <- replicate(N, matrix(rnorm(Tdim*K), ncol=K), simplify = F)

microbenchmark({
  I <- diag(Tdim)
  Z.m <- do.call(rbind, Z)
  meat.mat.GLS.kp <- t(Z.m)%*%(Siginv%x%I)%*%Z.m
}, {
  combs <- expand.grid(1:N, 1:N)
  cprods.GLS <- mapply(function(i,j) Siginv[j,i]*t(Z[[i]])%*%Z[[j]], combs[,1], combs[,2], SIMPLIFY = F)
  meat.mat.GLS <- Reduce("+", cprods.GLS)
}, {
  combs <- expand.grid(1:N, 1:N)
  cprods.GLS2 <- mapply(function(i,j) Siginv[j,i]*crossprod(Z[[i]],Z[[j]]), combs[,1], combs[,2], SIMPLIFY = F)
  meat.mat.GLS2 <- Reduce("+", cprods.GLS2)
}, times=5)

all.equal(meat.mat.GLS.kp, meat.mat.GLS, meat.mat.GLS2) # TRUE
```

Currently, the approaches compare as follows:

```
        min         lq       mean     median         uq        max neval cld
 4499.66564 4911.42674 4874.35170 4958.81553 4977.55873 5024.29187     5   b
   23.03861   23.09293   23.82407   23.29574   24.04696   25.64611     5  a 
   12.92261   13.08275   13.54088   13.15898   13.80212   14.73794     5  a
```

Comment: There's (only) 20% improvement over your third approach from using `mats <- sapply(1:N, function(j) crossprod(Reduce("+", lapply(Z, "*", Siginv[j, ])), Z[[j]])); Reduce("+", mats)`. In this way we have only `N` matrix multiplications. But surely Rcpp solution would give something much better.